# Changing the frame of UISearchBar's cancel button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios7, uisearchbar

I have a `UISearchBar` which I have been trying long to customise. I have successfully changed the appearance (Using custom images for backgrounds) of both its cancel button and the `UITextField`. Now I am not able to change the frames of these views using the `[UIView setFrame:]` command. Any idea why they might not be changing?